# Using Google.GData in C# to update POP3 settings

Tags: gdata, google-email-settings-api

I'm creating a desktop app using C#. I've downloaded the `Google.GData.Application` to start working with the API. From [this link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-settings/#manage_pop_settings) I found this code:

```
            var service = new GoogleMailSettingsService("my domain", "API KEY");
            service.setUserCredentials("my username", "my pass");

            var res = service.UpdatePop("my username", "true", "ALL_MAIL", "KEEP");
```

I created a simple console app and ran this code (it is the only code running). However whenever I run it, I get an exception with the `403` status code. My question is:

1. Is there anything wrong I've done? I mean, is there any additional step(s) I need to take? I've got the `my domain` and `API key` parts from [here](https://accounts.google.com/ManageDomain). I registered a domain and added the code and information to get the codes.
2. Is there any way to not use my domain? This app is not for me and is not a web app that is on a specific domain. It's a desktop app and is expected to run on any machine with .Net installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the user you are authenticating with is an administrator for the Google Apps domain.

The API Key is not required when using ClientLogin (i.e. authentication with username/password), the second parameter for the GoogleMailSettingsService constructor is just a string identifying your application.

Comment: OK. Maybe I got it wrong. What I want to do is this: I want to create a simple class that gets a gmail user's username/password and enable the POP3 settings to `All Mail`. I don't know about the admin part... Could you please help me?

Comment: The Email Settings API only works for Google Apps domain users, not with gmail.com accounts.

Comment: So is there any API for Gmail?